# Is it possible to construct circle $(DEC)$ with ruler and compass alone

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

I'm trying to draw this figure:

[image]

Given:

- $\omega - \odot(O,OX=R)$
- $\ell \perp OX$
- $\gamma = (ABE)$ is given, it has radius $r$ and it is tangent to $\ell$ at $A$ and $\omega$ at $B$.

I'm trying to find point $D$ such that $(DEC)$ is also tangent to $\omega$ (in $C$) and $\ell$ (in $D$) and $D$ is colinear to $E = (DEC) \cap (AEB)$ and $B$.

My attempt was with analytic geometry after getting stuck with the basic results you can see above.

It didn't get pretty.

Let's call $Z = \ell \cap OX$ and define $x_0 = ZO > 0$.

$AZ = d_r$, so $d_r^2 = (R+x_0)(R-x_0-2r)$

If $\rho$ is the radius of $(DEC)$ and $d_{\rho}^2 = (R+x_0)(R-x_0-2\rho)$

Let's finally call $\square = (R+x_0)(1-\frac rR) + \frac{d_r-d_{\rho}}{\rho-r}(\frac rR d_{\rho} - d_r)$

The equation that I've found that solves $\rho  = f(R,r,x_0)$ is:

$(\square \cdot r \cdot (\rho-r))^2 = ((R+x_0)(d_r-d_{\rho})^2 + \square \cdot (R+x_0+r)(\rho - r))^2 + (\rho-r)^2((R+x_0)(d_r-d_{\rho}) + d_r \cdot \square)^2$

I kinda can't expand it with my notebook tho, is there any smart way to construct this image?

Comment: The distance $|AE|$ turns out to be (relatively) "nice". If I'm translating my notation to yours correctly, that distance is
$$|AE| = \frac{R^2-(d_r^2+x_0^2)}{\sqrt{d_r^2+x_0^2+4x_0 R+3R^2}}$$ That's certainly a constructible length.

Comment: wow that is a very impressive result! If it is correct you solved the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's diagram correctly indicates that $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$, and the radical axis of the smaller circles all pass through $X'$. (The first two collinearities follow from dilating the semicircle on $\overline{XX'}$ with respect to $B$ and $C$. The third is less obvious, but since OP is aware of it we'll take it as "known".)

---

Altering notation considerably, consider a circle with diameter $\overline{PQ}$, take $\overline{OA}\perp\overline{PQ}$ (where $O$ is not necessarily the center of the circle), and $B$ on $\overline{OA}$. Extending $\overline{PA}$ and $\overline{PB}$ gives points of tangency $A'$ and $B'$.

[image]

Define $\alpha := \angle APQ$ and $\beta := \angle BPQ$, and also
$$p := |OP| \qquad q := |OQ| \qquad a := |OA|=p \tan\alpha \qquad b := |OB|=p\tan\beta \tag1$$
Coordinatizing with $O$ at the origin, we have
$$P = (-p,0) \qquad Q = ( q, 0) \qquad A = (0,a)=(0,p\tan\alpha) \qquad B = (0,b)=(0,p\tan\beta) \tag2$$
Also, since $|PA'|=(p+q)\cos\alpha$ and $|PB'|=(p+q)\cos\beta$, we can write
$$\begin{align}
A' &= P + (p+q)\cos\alpha\;(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha) = \frac{p}{a^2+p^2}\;(pq-a^2,a(p+q))\\[4pt]
B' &= P + (p+q)\cos\beta\; (\cos\beta, \sin\beta)  = \frac{p}{b^2+p^2}\;(pq-b^2,b(p+q))
\end{align} \tag3$$

Let $E$ be the intersection of $\overline{A'B}$ and the radical axis of the two circles. Conveniently, since the radical axis must pass through the midpoint of tangent segment $\overline{AB}$, we don't need to know much else about the circles (centers, radii, etc) to know the axis' equation. In fact, *we don't even assume that the circles meet or that $E$ lies on either circle*.

Without *too* much trouble, we find that
$$E = \left(\frac{p(p q-a^2)}{a^2+2p^2+pq}, \frac{p (p + q)(a + b)}{a^2+2p^2+pq}\right) \tag4$$
Conveniently, *the $x$-coordinate is independent of $B$*. That is, all possible $E$-points lie on the line
$$x = \frac{p(p q-a^2)}{a^2+2p^2+pq} \tag5$$

[image]

For OP's specific needs —where the circles *do* meet and $E$ *does* lie on both— we take $E$ to be the intersection of this auxiliary line and the $A$-circle. So, "all we need to" is provide a construction for that line; this is actually pretty easy: we exploit the extreme positions of point $B$.

[image]

Extend $\overline{OA}$ to meet the circle at $S$ and $T$. Let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of $\overline{AS}$ and $\overline{AT}$, and extend $\overline{PM}$ and $\overline{PN}$ to meet $\overline{A'S}$ and $\overline{A'T}$ at $M'$ and $N'$. Then $\overleftrightarrow{M'N'}$ is the auxiliary line whose intersections with the $A$-circle are candidates for OP's point $E$. (Either point will do.) From there, although this isn't shown in the figure, we can extend $\overline{A'E}$ to meet $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ at $B$, which defines the $B$-circle. Done.

Comment: wait, I moved point $B$ in $\ell$ and point $E$ moved, therefore it's coordinates must depend on $B$. I shall check your point $E$ soon

Comment: @hellofriends: $E$ moves, but its $x$-coordinate doesn't change.

Comment: how is that possible? It's distance from the line changes as soon as I can I will check the coordinates for $E$

Comment: you defined $E$ as the meeting of line $BA'$ so what I did was wrong and I've checked your points $A'$ and $B'$ and they are correct

Comment: ok what you did is 100% correct, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @hellofriends: For fun, I added an animation to show the locus of the $E$-points. I still wonder if this *means* anything. :)

Comment: @hellofriends: It occurred to me that the $E$-locus being a line greatly simplifies the target construction. No weird proportions, no perpendiculars; just midpoints and intersections. I've updated my answer.

Comment: yeah I would love a synthetic explanation about this locus. How about I start a bounty for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116076/discussion-between-hellofriends-and-blue).

Comment: @hellofriends: I've come to realize that the $E$-locus being a line isn't particularly *significant*. After all, it has nothing to do with the circles or tangents or anything that makes the overall problem interesting. All that matters are the fixed points $P$, $A$, $A'$ (whose collinearity may-or-may-not matter) and a point $B$ moving along some line (whose incidence with $A$ may-or-may-not matter). In this light, the locus traced by the intersection of the $\overline{A'B}$ and the line joining $P$ to the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ "shouldn't" be all that complicated. (I'm not a chatter.)

Comment: @hellofriends: BTW: A quick GeoGebra test shows that the collinearity of $P$, $A$, $A'$ and the incidence of $A$ with the line $B$ travels *both* seem to matter for the $E$-locus to be a line. At worst, without collinearity and/or incidence, since $B$ can travel infinitely far, the locus is an unbounded conic (probably always a hyperbola). ... Anyway, because of the "extended discussions" warning and my aversion to chat, this may be my last comment on the topic.